# Neo4j count the number of related nodes

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher, aggregation

I'm starting studying the Neo4j and the Cypher Queries, and I need some help to understand and get some results.

I have this MATCH query:

```
MATCH (p:EntidadePessoa {id: 168750})-[rd:SE_RELACIONA]->(d:Documento)<--(p2) 
 where p2:EntidadePessoa or p2:EntidadeOrganizacao 
 return p,d,p2
```

That results this:

[image: graph image]

Commencing with EntidadePessoa id:168750, I want the count of EntidadeDocumento directcly linked to EntidadePessoa id:168750, is this case 2, and the count of each Entidade* that is linked to EntidadeDocumento, in this case 4 for each EntidadeDocumento.

I tried some queries, but none give me the results I wanted, the count number is never the numbers I wanted.

Could you help with that?

Comment: Are you looking for 2,4,4 or 2,8? Could you also include an example output you are expecting, along with the desired format/aliases?

Comment: I'm looking for 2,4,4. the @Thennan answer brought what I wanted! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. A query to get the count of d nodes connected to p (id: 168750).

```
    MATCH (p:EntidadePessoa {id: 168750})-[rd:SE_RELACIONA]->(d:Documento)
    RETURN p.id as `nodeId`, count(d) as `connectedCount`
```

output:

> ```
> nodeId    connectedCount
> 168750    2
> ```

2. A query with a subquery to look at just d:Documento, incoming links from p2, omitting (p:EntidadePessoa {id: 168750}) and counting p2s for each d node:

```
    CALL
    {MATCH (p)-[rd:SE_RELACIONA]->(d:Documento)
    WHERE p.id=168750
    RETURN  d,p.id as `topid`}
    MATCH (p2)-->(d)
    WHERE (p2:EntidadePessoa or p2:EntidadeOrganizacao) AND p2.id<>topid
    //p2.id<>topid ensures p is not included in count(p2) 
    RETURN d.id as `nodeId`, count(p2) as `connectedCount`
```

output:

> ```
> nodeId    connectedCount
> 164532    4
> 164552    4
> ```

3. Combine both these results with a UNION:

```
    MATCH (p:EntidadePessoa {id: 168750})-[rd:SE_RELACIONA]->(d:Documento)
    RETURN p.id as `nodeId`, count(d) as `connectedCount`UNION
    CALL
    {MATCH (p)-[rd:SE_RELACIONA]->(d:Documento)
    WHERE p.id=168750
    RETURN  d,p.id as `topid`}
    MATCH (p2)-->(d)
    WHERE (p2:EntidadePessoa or p2:EntidadeOrganizacao) AND p2.id<>topid
    //p2.id<>topid ensures p is not included in count(p2) 
    RETURN d.id as `nodeId`, count(p2) as `connectedCount`
```

output:

> ```
> nodeId    connectedCount
> 168750    2
> 164552    4
> 164552    4
> ```

Comment: why the subquery is the almost the same of the first match? Why didn't you use the nodeId instead of the topid in the last match?

I'm just trying to understand the query.

Comment: The subquery is indeed the same as the first match. Using it as a reference to get all the nodes connected to d. Splitting the relationship this way allows us to look at d connected to p and then filter out P2 from the result. I've used  topid as an intermediate variable. If the query has to be run for a different p node, you have to change the I'd just in one place per query.

Comment: Ok.
I got the same result with this query:

` MATCH (p:sisdoc_EntidadePessoa {id: 168750})-[rd:sisdoc_SE_RELACIONA]->(d:sisdoc_Documento)       
RETURN p.id as `nodeId`, count(d) as `connectedCount`
union
MATCH (p2)--(d2:sisdoc_Documento)
where (p2:sisdoc_EntidadePessoa or p2:sisdoc_EntidadeOrganizacao) and p2.id<> 168750
RETURN d2.id as `nodeId`, count(p2) as `connectedCount``

Comment: `MATCH (p2)--(d2:sisdoc_Documento) where (p2:sisdoc_EntidadePessoa or p2:sisdoc_EntidadeOrganizacao) and p2.id<> 168750 RETURN d2.id as nodeId, count(p2) as connectedCount`
Will look for all p2s related to d2. and all d2s may not be related to p({id: 168750}). This is why I had matched p-->d in the subquery and then looked for p2s connected to d in the outer query. This way we restrict our search to document nodes connected to p({id: 168750}) and then look for incoming relationships for only those document nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result. This is similar to count and group_by in sql.

```
 MATCH (p:EntidadePessoa {id: 168750})-[rd:SE_RELACIONA]->(d:Documento)<--(p2) 
  where p2:EntidadePessoa or p2:EntidadeOrganizacao 
 With p, count(distinct d) as cnt_d, count(p2) as cnt_p2
  return p, cnt_d, cnt_p2
```

Comment: This query didn't bring the result: 2, 4,4. It brougth: p, cnt_d=8 and cnt_p2=8

Comment: pls add distinct keyword in the count to remove duplicates

Comment: I put the DISTINCT the result now is: cnt_d=2 and cnt_p2=5

Comment: don't put distinct on cnt_p2. Put distinct on cnt_d only